# How do you optimize the FuelUX package for deployment with Grunt and Bower?

Tags: gruntjs, bower, fuelux

I'm new to Grunt and Bower. When I install FuelUX using bower, it puts about 77 megabytes of files in my app/components/fuelux directory. The default Gruntfile.js that gets generated by yo (using the angular generator) copies all of those file during a Grunt build.

I'm pretty sure I don't need to deploy all those file to my web/app server. What's the best way to ensure that only the necessary files get created in my Grunt dist output directory?

Comment: Is there a way to modify grunt to exclude read me files? and example folders etc? if so i would love to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you get the author of the package to make use of the `ignore` property for bower.json to ignore everything that isn't needed.

I'm not sure which generator you used, but generator-webapp only copies over what you explicitly define in your Gruntfile/index.html.